# Grouping an array based on a key value returning object not array

Tags: javascript, react-native, reduce

I've seen many questions on this subject on Stack Overflow, however, they all seem to be returning a single object. (Not what I want)

I have an array below;

```
const locations = [
    {"city": "London", "district": "Brixton", "id": "Eue3uFjUHKi6wh73QZLX"},
    {"city": "Manchester", "district": "Bury", "id": "QZiiUBgzZaJt2HcahELT"},
    {"city": "London", "district": "Hackney", "id": "v2itdyO4IPXAMhIU8wce"}
]
```

I would like to map this array into sections based on the `"city"` key.

My expected output is;

```
 [
    {
       city: "London",
       data: [
          {
             city: "London",
             district: "Brixton",
             id: "Eue3uFjUHKi6wh73QZLX"
          },
          {
             city: "London",
             district: "Hackney",
             id: "v2itdyO4IPXAMhIU8wce"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       city: "Manchester",
       data: [
          {
             city: "Manchester",
             district: "Bury",
             id: "QZiiUBgzZaJt2HcahELT"
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

I have tried the below;

```
const groupedLocations = locations.reduce((groups, item) => {
  const { city } = item;
  if (!groups[city]) {
    groups[city] = [];
  }
  groups[city].push(item);
  return groups;
}, {});
```

However, this returns an object not an array.

Comment: After you create the object, use `Object.values()` to get its properties as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code:

```js
const groupedLocations = locations.reduce((groups, item) => {
  const { city } = item;
  
  let relatedGroup = groups.find((group) => group.city === city);
  if (!relatedGroup) {
    relatedGroup = { city, data: [] };
    groups.push(relatedGroup);
  }

  relatedGroup.data.push(item);
  return groups;
}, []);
```

`reduce` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#return_value) the type of whatever is returned from its reducer function. In your case it was an object, and that's why you got an object at the end.
I started with an array and each step I looked in the array to find the related group and push the city into that group's `data` list.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: This is exactly the function I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer based on normal loops without using high order functions:**

```js
const locations = [
  { city: "London", district: "Brixton", id: "Eue3uFjUHKi6wh73QZLX" },
  { city: "Manchester", district: "Bury", id: "QZiiUBgzZaJt2HcahELT" },
  { city: "London", district: "Hackney", id: "v2itdyO4IPXAMhIU8wce" },
];

function ObjectCreatorHelper(arr, keyMatcher, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
  let newObj = {};
  newObj[keyMatcher] = arr[firstIndex][keyMatcher];
  newObj["data"] = [];
  if (secondIndex != null)
    newObj["data"].push(arr[firstIndex], arr[secondIndex]);
  else newObj["data"].push(arr[firstIndex]);

  return newObj;
}

function grouper(arr, keyMatcher) {
  // to make optimization because in runnig loop   the length of array should not be calculated
  let len = arr.length;
  let temp = [];
  let arrLenDecrementor = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < len - arrLenDecrementor; i++) {
    let isFound = false;
    let key1 = arr[i];
    for (let j = i + 1; j < len - arrLenDecrementor; j++) {
      let key2 = arr[j];

      if (key1[keyMatcher] && key2[keyMatcher]) {
        if (key1[keyMatcher] == key2[keyMatcher]) {
          //
          let n = ObjectCreatorHelper(arr, keyMatcher, i, j);
          temp.push(n);
          isFound = true;

          //delete the matched array value no longer needed
          arr.splice(j, 1);
          // decrease the lengh of array to make loop run less
          arrLenDecrementor++;
          //
        }
      }
    }
    //if not found the duplicate key then
    if (!isFound) {
      let n = ObjectCreatorHelper(arr, keyMatcher, i, null);
      temp.push(n);
    }
  }

  return temp;
}

let result = grouper(locations, "city");

console.log(result);
```